# Nisnevich local model structure is a Bousfield localisation of global projective model structure

Tags: model-categories

Suppose $\Delta^{op}Psh(Sm/k)$ is the category of simplicial presheaves on the category $Sm/k$ of finite type smooth schemes over $k$, endowed with Nisnevich topology. $\Delta^{op}Psh(Sm/k)$ has two different model structures: Nisnevich local model structure (by Jardine) - weak equivalences are stalkwise, cofibrations are monomorphism and fibrations are defined using right lifting property with respect to acyclic cofibrations; and the other one is global projective model structure (by Bousfield-Kan-Hirschhorn) where weak equivalences and fibrations are sectionwise and cofibrations are defined using left lifting property with respect to acyclic fibrations.
Then is Nisnevich local model structure is the left Bousfield localisation of global projective model structure with respect to some class of maps? If it is please specify the class of maps or is there any relation between these two model structures.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy diagnostic: a model structure is a left Bousfield localisation of another if and only if it has the same cofibrations and more weak equivalences.
That is:

**Proposition.** A model structure with cofibrations $\mathcal{C}'$ and weak equivalences $\mathcal{W}'$ is a left Bousfield localisation of a model structure cofibrations $\mathcal{C}$ and weak equivalences $\mathcal{W}$ if and only if $\mathcal{C} = \mathcal{C}'$ and $\mathcal{W} \subseteq \mathcal{W}'$.

Furthermore if you know that one model structure is a left Bousfield localisation of another, then it is a left Bousfield localisation with respect to the (bigger) class of weak equivalences.
This is basically tautological if you think about it.

The Nisnevich local model structure you are asking about has more cofibrations than the global projective model structure, so it is not a left Bousfield localisation of the global projective model structure.
Rather, it is a left Bousfield localisation of the global *injective* model structure (a.k.a. the Heller model structure).
The global injective model structure and the global projective model structure have the same weak equivalences, so they are Quillen equivalent, but neither one is a Bousfield localisation of the other.

Comment: Thanks Sir.  So Nisnevich local model structure is the left Bousfield localisation of Heller model structure w.r.t local weak equivalence (is it a good class of maps for this Bousfield localisation of Heller model structure to get Nisnevich local model structure or there is other class of maps ). A priori, is these any relation between Nisnevich local model structure and global projective model structure?

Comment: One must distinguish between the abstract notion of Bousfield localisation and the concrete theorem that tells us when Bousfield localisations exist. The class of local weak equivalences is too large to apply the theorem, so one has to prove an intermediate result to reduce the class of local weak equivalences to a more manageable set.

Comment: Yahh. I also thought the class of local weak equivalence is a large class for Bousfield localisation. So what is the class (better class) of maps so that taking left Bousfield localisation of Heller model structure w.r.t this will yield Nisnevich local model structure. There must be some good class I can't find.

Comment: Why don't you look in Jardine's papers? It must be in there.